# Bootstrap 4.5 Carousel image pull up

Tags: css, image, bootstrap-4

I have a customized carrousel. What i want to achieve is shown below as image. I want to pull up images a bit top on the carousel.

I set up `.carousel-inner` css to `overflow: visible;`and img css to `margin-top: -33px` in order to achieve what i want but that way when carousel sliding content is mixing up (because of the overflow-x:visible and if i set `overflow-x: hidden;` my pull up on top is became not visible).

### GOAL

[image: goal]

### ISSUE

[image: Issue]

So whats the correct way of pull up image in carousel items out of whole carousel element?

**Update:**

Added codepen link to issue:

https://codepen.io/meowornever/pen/gOwGxGy

Comment: add/update a css into ..carousel-inner  { overflow: hidden } and manage image using background image

Comment: Hello @Md.AbuSayed. Could you give me a codepen sample?

Comment: you can visite this link:  https://jsfiddle.net/ekgd964v/1/

Comment: @Md.AbuSayed thats not what i want mate. All i want is pull up every image in carousel-item from the whole carrousel a bit like : margin-top:-33px; But Carousel's .carousel-inner class's overflow:hidden rule is not allowing me to do that.

Comment: I had pulled up upto carousel-inner. The problem is it's parent div

Comment: @AnwarHossen so you mean  <div id="carousel-third" class="carousel slide" style="background-color: #f2f2f2;" data-ride="carousel"> by the parent div?

Comment: Yes. You are right

Comment: i still stuck on that